# Clipboard JS not copying button data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clipboard, clipboard.js

I am trying to copy a simple URL which is bound to a button. The console successfully logs the data but it doesn't return the value to be pasted. Please note that the `data-clipboard-text` changes on an AJAX call. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-clipboard-text="pedigreetrail/eyJpdNkYWQxZDRkYjQzN2NkZWQ1MTQ4OTg2MiJ9/share" id="share-button">
  <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

```js
new ClipboardJS("#share-button", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    console.log($(trigger).data('clipboard-text'));
    return trigger.getAttribute('data-clipboard-text');
  }
});
```